CORS Misconfiguration and the Preflight Request (OPTIONS)
I know there are some excellent answers to this question, but I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. If you can answer or point me to the answer, I would greatly appreciate it.
My application is reflecting the Origin header in the response of the request as Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to true on a GET request. However, in the preflight (OPTIONS) request, only Access-Control-Allow-Origin is reflected. There is no Access-Control-Allow-Credentials at all. When I try to make an XHR or fetch request with including the credentials, I cannot pass the preflight (OPTIONS) request because there is no Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header on the response of the preflight.
I've read in other answers that basic requests do not make a preflight request before the main request. My GET request is without any specific headers, but it's still making the preflight request before the real request and stopping the GET.
My question is: Is it possible to bypass the preflight (OPTIONS) request and do the GET request directly?

Here is a description of which conditions need to apply for the browser not to make a preflight request. There are no other ways to circumvent a preflight as it is a security measure.
But a more correct approach would be to configure your server to respond with Access-Control-Allow-Credentials on preflights as well. However you need to be aware of the security implications of this.

If the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials are set, is it possible to get the bearer token from the Authorization header? That is my worry.
